# How do you follow your close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

How do you follow a question after close-voting it?

I know at least two reasons to do it:

- pure curiosity
- when wanting to know if the community shared your thinking about the question and decided to close-vote too

Comment: If I *really* have a particular reason to care, I leave it open in a browser tab. But generally, I can't imagine why I'd be very concerned about a question that I thought should be closed.

Comment: you can post a comment and check it out later.

Comment: ... due to a bug (?) you can't delete the comment if the question is migrated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't. I don't see a reason to.